# How to make text on the same line different font without using extra divs?

Tags: css, html

I have an overlayed bar on an image and have text inside it,

```
aasimAZAM
```

I want the aasim to be a thin font and the AZAM to be a bolder font.

My CSS is

```
h4 {position:relative; top:-60px; left: 0px; width: 100%; font-family:"Futura Bk BT"; color:#F00;}
h4 span { color: white; font: 12/24px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -1px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */ background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); padding: 8px;}
h5 {position:relative; top:-60px; left: 0px; width: 100%; font-family:"Futura Std ExtraBold";color:#F00;}
h5 span { color: white; font: 12/24px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -1px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */ background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); padding: 8px;
```

and the HTML is

```
<div class="picturebox"><img src="images/001.jpg" width="192" height="192" alt="001" /><h4><span>aasim</span></h4><h5><span>AZAM</span></h5></div>
```

the problem is that the span is on two different lines?

how do I either fix this code so that the text is on the same line and span and have the different fonts? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the spans, `<h4>` and `<h5>` are already considered headers, which are always put on a new line.

If you don't intend on these being headers (which it doesn't like you do), don't use `h<n>` tags. If you have to, put `display: inline;` in the css for your `<h4>` and `<h5>` styles.

Comment: Unless you change css for H4 and H5 :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
h4 { width: 100%; font-family:"Futura Bk BT"; color:#F00; display:inline; color: #dadada; font: 12/24px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -1px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0);  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); padding: 8px; font-weight:normal}

h5 {width: 100%; font-family:"Futura Std ExtraBold";color:#F00; display:inline; color: #dadada; font: 12/24px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -1px; background: rgb(0, 0, 0);  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); padding: 8px; font-weight:bold;}
```

And html should be:

```
<div class="picturebox"><img src="images/001.jpg" width="192" height="192" alt="001" /><h4>aasim</h4><h5>AZAM</h5></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get why you are using position:relative; for the h4 and h5 tags

Anyway try the following css, code hope it useful for you

```
h5 {
        color: #FF0000;
        float: left;
        font-family: "Futura Std ExtraBold";    
        padding: 8px;    
        width: auto;
    }


    h4 {
        color: #FF0000;
        float: left;
        font-family: "Futura Bk BT";    
        padding: 8px;   
        width: auto;
    }
```